# AngularJS simple Factory related error

Tags: angularjs

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']); 

demoApp.factory = ('simpleFactory', function () {

    var factory = {};
    var customers = [{ name: 'Touqeer', city: 'Multan' },
           { name: 'Arslan', city: 'RWP' },
           { name: 'Saleem', city: 'Taxila' }];``

    factory.getCustomers = function () {
        return customers;`enter code here`
    };

    return factory;
});

demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, simpleFactory) {
    debugger
    $scope.customers = simpleFactory.getCustomers();
});
```

Error It shows :
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/unpr?p0=simpleFactoryProvider%20%3C-impleFactory
    at Error (native)

Answer (score 1):

```
demoApp.factory = ('simpleFactory', function () {
```

should be

```
demoApp.factory('simpleFactory', function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

Hy, I made a plunker so you could see into how it should work: [Plunker LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/jF5bPGDIWi2v3wGh9lWt?p=preview), because I think you will run in to some other stuff too. Stuff that I found to be wrong in the code that you provided:

- `demoApp.factory = ('simpleFactory', function(){...})`, should be `demoApp.factory('simpleFactory', function () {...})` - **because you are calling a method, not providing one**.
- If you want to put a comment, you should use `//` or  `/* comment for multiple lines */`,
  **not just put 'string'**
- Also if you provide private variables, you should keep their names different, like '_customers', it's a small thing, but it will help other people to understand what is your intention.